# Выполнение одного и того же запроса в рамках одной сессии SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

SQLAlchemy знаю плохо, поэтому прошу вас подсказать, что произошло в моей ситуации

```py
obj = db_session.query(Product).get(current_id)
print(obj.prop) # test

# Делаю запрос, по которому вьюха меняет свойство prop у obj
reguest.get(f'/change-obj/{current_id}/')

# Беру тот же самый объект из базы еще раз, prop не изменился
obj = db_session.query(Product).get(current_id)
print(obj.prop) # test
```

Вопрос собственно в том, почему при повторном запросе в obj не записывается измененный объект, почему ORM не идет в БД за ним.

Решить проблему помогает вызов `expunge`, но я не понимаю как это в итоге работает

```py
obj = db_session.query(Product).get(current_id)
print(obj.prop) # test
db_session.expunge(obj)

reguest.get(f'/change-obj/{current_id}')

obj = db_session.query(Product).get(current_id)
print(obj.prop) # new value
```

Comment: Вы работаете с view (представлениями) в базе данных? Они материализованы?

Comment: @SimonOsipov что значит материализованы? Код не мой, всех нюансов не знаю, но суть в том, что по обращению к определенному адресу, меняется значение поля у БД. Код, приведенный в примере работает в тесте. Я беру объект первый раз, проверяю, что поле равно одному значению. Потом делаю запрос по нужному адресу. Проверяю что значение изменилось. Но если не использовать `expunge`, то оно как будто бы не меняется. Хотя в базе меняется. Я думал это связано с какой-то оптимизацией одинаковых запросов или вроде того.

Comment: Материализована == закеширована. Посмотрите код создания view (представления) в базе данных. Если она закеширована, то ваше представление как раз верное.